# Center a view in relation to another

Tags: android, view

The code below is not centering the view object vertically in relation to the `TextView` but it is stuck in the top.

How can I get it centered vertically?

Thank  you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/station" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_TV"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/label_TV"
        android:background="@color/divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centverVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:text="@string/station" />

    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centverVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_TV"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/label_TV"
    android:background="@color/divider" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EDITED

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="AAA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Line" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/label_TV"
    android:background="@color/line_divider" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_TV"
    android:text="BBB" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically you just need to set the parent layout's height to match parent and then use layout_centverVertical="true" instead.

Comment: 'android:layout_centerVertical="true"' centers the view in relation to its container. This RelativeLayout has other views before and after the included 2 view used for this example. is there a way to get the same effect without having to create a separate RL container for it?

Comment: Jiyeh: I need the 3 "lines" (AAA, Line -------- and 888) be stacked towards the top of the screen and not spread out over the whole screen height.;)

Comment: Okay. Try the edited code again. Just change the RL's height to wrap_content.

Comment: how can the line remain vertically centered after the height of the label_TV is set to @dimen/title_height is the original problem.